# How broad is the definition of sodomy?

Tags: meaning, etymology

[In this article](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/2011/05/14/2011-05-14_top_french_politician_dominique_strausskahn_dragged_of_flight_at_jfk_accused_of_.html), a top French official is in trouble for sodomizing a maid. Yet, the article says that he forced her to perform oral sex. I always understood sodomy as involving anal as that seemed to be what was going on in Sodom in the Bible. Then I looked at [this definition](http://onelook.com/?w=sodomize&ls=a) on Onelook.com and found that it includes bestiality.

Did other taboo sex acts just get lumped in with sodomy over the years, or did it include all those from the beginning?

Comment: "Sodomize" also sometimes implies the use of force or coercion, which might be the reason for the word choice here. See http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/sodomize

Comment: Legal definitions in the U.S. varied widely until they were struck down by in 2003 by the Supreme Court in [Lawrence v. Texas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_v._Texas).

Comment: For an interesting (and useful) list of what you can do to whom and where - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy_laws_in_the_United_States

Comment: If only there were laws about putting one's nose all up in peoples' business.

Comment: Yeah, some old sodomy laws in the US essentially declared any extramarital sex to be "sodomy" and hence illegal.

Answer (score 11):

You probably already know that [*sodomy*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sodomy&allowed_in_frame=0) is derived from "sin of Sodom" from the Bible story in which God rained fire and brimstone down on Sodom and Gomorrah for certain reasons.

My understanding is that some interpretations of these reasons are that God's angel messengers were (nearly) raped by the residents, so this meant that God objected to homosexuality.  Therefore the "sin of Sodom" was homosexuality, which naturally was further interpreted as anal sex between two men.  However, other interpretations might suggest any kind of "unnatural" sex act, including bestiality, oral sex, anal sex between any two people, and pretty much anything that's not missionary-style intravaginal intercourse.

Since what actually constitutes the "sin of Sodom" is open to debate, I imagine the definition of the word *sodomy* is also pretty fluid.

The dictionary definitions that I have found generally specify *sodomy* as anal sex, some include oral sex, and some include bestiality. [This article](http://www.slate.com/id/2075271/) has a quick reference as far as legal definitions of sodomy in the US.

I don't know a good history of sodomy, so I hope someone posts one, but I think that it is likely that oral sex and bestiality have been part of the definition since the beginning.

Comment: This makes good sense. I wonder about the town of Sodom way back in Bible times. Did the name of the town have any related meaning back then, or did it develop its negative meaning entirely after the fact? My only issue with your response is your citation of the Slate article. At the end the author makes this bogus claim, "The word "sodomy" itself is something of a misnomer, since the Bible contains no mention of homosexual conduct among the residents of Sodom." You would have to be almost completely Bible ignorant to believe this. But, I know many people are. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too.  I linked to the article merely because it offered some resources for legal definitions, as opposed to dictionary definitions.

Comment: There was a lot of warring and hostility between Sodom (and some of the other kingdoms in the Jordan River Valley) and the kingdoms that might be thought of as allied with Abraham.  It would make sense to me that Sodom was thought of the way we might think of Las Vegas--as Sin City.

Comment: You could delete the word *Christian* from your first sentence, as this passage is found in all versions of the Bible.

Comment: I am curious to know why the term *Christian* is considered misleading by the anonymous editor, yes the Old Testament is  first and foremost Judaic, but the "Bible" includes both the Old and the New Testaments, and *sodomy* is also mentioned in the latter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy#New_Testament

Comment: @Mari-LouA: yeah, I don't really see how it is "misleading." The adjective "Christian" was not inaccurate; and it seems likely to me that the term "sodomy" came into use in areas that were mostly culturally Christian. The new version is certainly correct as well. Perhaps someone thought using the term "Christian Bible" carried an implication that the story is not found in non-Christian bibles. I can see the argument for that.

Comment: @sumelic and yet two users approved of this edit, so there are three users who agree the term, Christian,  is misleading.  I'm sure Kit Z Fox will decide for herself if the edit should remain or be rolled back.

Answer (score 6):

Sodomy most definitely does mean "anal sex" and usually connotes the male-to-male variety.

Origin from Etymonline:

> **sodomy** 
>   c.1300, from O.Fr. sodomie, from L.L. peccatum Sodomiticum "anal sex," lit. "sin of Sodom," from L. Sodoma (see Sodom).

NOAD gives a little more info:

> ORIGIN Middle English : from medieval Latin *sodomia*, from late Latin *peccatum Sodomiticum* ‘sin of Sodom’ (after Gen. 19:5, which implies that the men of Sodom practiced homosexual rape) (see Sodom).

But NOAD also includes this extra tidbit about oral sex:

> **sodomy** |ˈsädəmē|
>   *noun*
>   sexual intercourse involving anal or oral copulation.

Probably the distinction is blurred; people of a certain era weren't all that clear on what  the "sin of Sodom" might mean, and preachers were no doubt loath to explain in detail. So the word probably acquired the extra meaning of "anything that good, church-going folk might construe to be an abomination of the sexual kind." Oral sex would have been included under that rubric.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the original meaning of *sodomy* was:

> Originally: any form of sexual intercourse considered to be unnatural. Now chiefly: anal intercourse

This word was first used in the 13th century:

> 1297    R. Gloucester's Chron. (Rolls) 9038   Mid þe vile sunne of sodomye yproued hii were echon.

Even in the early 1900s, it still seems to be used to mean sexual acts besides anal intercourse:

> 1905    H. B. Lazell Clark & Marshall's Treat. Law of Crimes (ed. 2) ix. v. §461. 706   Sodomy or buggery, which is sexual connection by a man or woman with a brute animal, or connection per anum by a man with any other man, or with a woman, is a felony at common law.

However, by the late 1900s it was used as we use it now--to primarily refer to the acts of anal intercourse:

> 1980    D. C. Knutsen Homosexality & Law 33   Missouri has reduced consensual sodomy by adults in private from a felony to misdeneanour status.

So the phrase *sodomy* started out with a very broad definition, which then became more specific as time went on. As Kith mentioned, the only "good" type of sexual intercourse would have been heterosexual inter-vaginal missionary intercourse.

Comment: "...the only 'good' type of sexual intercourse would have been heterosexual inter-vaginal missionary intercourse." Also, it had to be for the purposes of procreation.

Answer (score 1):

I think originally it might have been meant to describe any sexual act between two people or man and/or woman and animal that could not result in procreation of humans.

Answer (score 0):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy_law)

> The precise sexual acts meant by the
>   term sodomy are rarely spelled out in
>   the law, but are typically understood
>   by courts to include any sexual act
>   deemed unnatural... These acts
>   typically include oral sex, anal sex
>   and bestiality