# Sodomy, but no "Gomorry"?

Tags: history, religion

Sodom and Gomorrah are two cities in the Abrahamic religions that were destroyed by brimstone and fire for their sins. Even though English speakers use both cities historically as metaphors for sin and homosexuality, only one of these cities has other words derived from it. We have sodomy and sodomites, but I haven't seen an equivalent for Gomorrah.

[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25408/137679) has looked into the question about the usage of the word sodomy and [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/189256/137679) about words derived from the name Gomorrah. I'm more interested in the history that explains why one city has words derived from it, and the other doesn't?

This question was posed before on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/3670i6/we_say_sodomized_but_not_gomorrized_why_do_we/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) with no satisfying answer. Other media also implies this question:

> The web cartoon The God and Devil Show had the Devil whisper the definition of "gomorrahmy" into Marilyn Manson's ear, playing on the common gag where one brings up Sodom and Gomorrah, mentions "sodomy", and then implies "gomorrahmy" was even worse.

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/NoodleIncident/WebComics)

Comment: "sodomy" is easier to write and say than ""gomorrahmy" . That's probably reason enough.

Comment: It's a folk (= false) etymology that ['gonorrhea' is related](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gonorrhea) to ['Gomorrah'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Gomorrah)

Comment: What would "gomorrahry" mean?

Comment: "Sodomy" is easier on the ears and just "rolls off the tongue", to borrow an expression from Jerry Seinfeld .. whereas "gomorrahry" sounds awful. I guess "Gomorry" would be short for "gomorrahry", but if you have "sodomy" already, why bother?

Comment: It isn't merely Gomorrah that is forgotten. Justice for Admah and Zeboim!

Comment: I've just looked at OED: † **Gomorr(h)ean, adj. and n.Obsolete. A. adj.  Of or pertaining to Gomorrah (see Genesis xviii, xix)** ++ 1581   J. Bell tr. W. Haddon & J. Foxe Against Jerome Osorius 37 b   *Gomorrhean and Sodomiticall brimstone.* But more to the point: **B. n. An inhabitant of Gomorrah; hence, one who follows the practices of its inhabitants.** 1551   J. Bale Actes Eng. Votaryes: 2nd Pt. f. lxx  *His dyabolycal rable of sorcerouse Gomorreanes.* It thus seems there was already a good word for "gommorahry" = sorcery; witchcraft..*

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in Genesis 18-20.  God is going to destroy both Gomorrah and Sodom because of their wicked ways.  Apparently, Abraham's brother, Lot, allowed two angels (but beware, here because the Greek word angeloi means literally 'messengers') to stay in his house for the night; but some of the Sodomites (which literally means 'citizens of Sodom') come round and hand over these messengers, apparently wanting to 'know' them.  As I am sure you know, this word can connote carnal 'knowledge' (as in "Adam knew his wife Eve", or Mary's query to the angel Gabriel: "How can this be, seeing I know not a man?".).  So the word 'Sodomy' acquired this association with the act of buggery.  No citizens of Gomorrah were involved in this strange encounter.  As to whether we are supposed to imagine that an angel could in fact have been subjected to such an attack, that question is neither answered not asked in Genesis.

Comment: The question asks about the non-wordness of 'GomorXXX'. This can't be answered satisfactorily. Sodomy apparently entered the lexicon as a Middle English term, from medieval Latin _sodomia_. Why there was no corresponding Latin equivalent involving  Gomorrah is at best off-topic as non-English, but along with all 'why is there no word for ...' questions, unhelpful.

Comment: Interesting theory...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, while it is true that asking 'why there is no word for . . .' often invites idle speculation, it seems odd to insist that **this** question '**can't** be answered satisfactorily' right below an answer that in fact **does** answer it.

Comment: It reasonably answers why there is the term 'sodomy'. We're told that Gomorrah endured what appears to be identical punishment for sins. Why isn't there a related term (saying that the narrative doesn't contain a record of any actual visit to Gomorrah is _not_ a reason). // Note that others agree that answers will be punts.

Comment: That the narrative does not contain an account of any **specific** incidents that took place in Gomorrah, is a satisfactory explanation of why there is no word for any specific acts that would be based on the name of that city.